# How to determine where the ) error is

Tags: sql-server

I have the following where statement and I keep getting an error relating to a ) and , when i run it the Incorrect Syntax error pops up. I cannot figure out where I am making the mistake I have rewritten it several times.

```
WHERE     (dbo.COL_V_Cost.RRDD NOT LIKE '12%') AND (dbo.COL_V_COST.RRDD NOT LIKE '13%') AND (dbo.COL_V_Cost.RRDD NOT LIKE '2706%') AND (dbo.COL_V_Cost.RRDD NOT LIKE '2707%') AND (dbo.COL_V_Cost.RRDD NOT LIKE '2331%') AND (dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.DEP_TYP_CD = 'H&S') AND (COL_V_COST.TNG_SYS_NR NOT ('0113','0197','0290','0489','0542','0974','1318','1322','1397','1401','1444','1446','1580'))
```

Comment: "IN" is missing before the list in the last clause

Comment: to find more esealy the error, split your condition/query on multiple lines where cond1 and cond2 or .... In the error message you will get a line number helping you ton find the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `IN` for the last filter:

```
WHERE (dbo.COL_V_Cost.RRDD NOT LIKE '12%') 
  AND (dbo.COL_V_COST.RRDD NOT LIKE '13%') 
  AND (dbo.COL_V_Cost.RRDD NOT LIKE '2706%') 
  AND (dbo.COL_V_Cost.RRDD NOT LIKE '2707%') 
  AND (dbo.COL_V_Cost.RRDD NOT LIKE '2331%') 
  AND (dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.DEP_TYP_CD = 'H&S') 
  AND (COL_V_COST.TNG_SYS_NR NOT IN ('0113','0197','0290','0489','0542','0974','1318','1322','1397','1401','1444','1446','1580'))
                                  ^-- this is missing
```

The correct syntax is `NOT IN`

Comment: Wow i cannot believe I actually missed that

Answer (score 0):

Your final AND should be "NOT IN"